# Read EXIF-data from a byte[]

Tags: android, arrays, byte, jpeg, exif

I am currently trying to get the EXIF-data from a photo in the form of a byte-array. The photo is taken directly from the camera and is therefore only available as the afore-mentioned byte[].

Now there are many EXIF-extracting libraries around - however, those only take BufferReader or, even worse, a FileStream. Seeing that I have hit a wall, I'd be willing to use a BufferReader to feed the byte[] to the library. But unfortunately, I don't know any short way around and don't want to implement my own BufferReader just to consume the byte[].

Additionally, I would like to not have to write the byte[] to the storage, then read it in again for the EXIF-information, because I want to rotate it accordingly and save the result. Therefore, the first time saving the file would be unreasonable, because I am going to save that very image in a orientation-corrected form anyway...

Any help would be great :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the afore-mentioned problem.

The fastest way of doing the image rotation is (imho) to get the phone rotation before taking the image and then simply rotating the PDF. This way, there is no need for any further library or overhead of reading the EXIF data.

The steps are like this:

1. Get rotation (via the acceleration sensor) and save it in a variable
2. Take the picture
3. Rotate the picture by the saved amount
4. Store the picture

Answer (score 0):

You could have done this by wrapping the `byte[]` with a `ByteArrayInputStream` and passing it to a library such as my [metadata-extractor](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor).